# MySQL query same interest

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find posts by users that I am not following but share same interests with.

I have this table structure:

> **Posts** - PostID, UserID, PostDate
>
> **Users** - UserID, NAME
>
> **Followers** - UserID, FollowerID
>
> **Interests** - InterestID, InterestName
>
> **UserInterests** - UserID, InterestID

Any idea how can I achieve this?

I have done this so far:

```
select * from posts p
inner join users u on u.idUsers = p.idUsers
where  p.idusers <> 1
 and p.idusers not in (
-- Gets the users whom I am Following
select users.idUsers
 from users
     inner join followers f on (f.idUsers=users.idUsers)
     inner join users u on (u.idUsers=f.FollowerID)
where f.FollowerID = 1
)
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: How far does your current query get you? What does it do? I take it you are user ID 1? (I'd guess you just need to modify your sub-select: if that gets users who you are following, you just need to get it to take into account who you share interests with).

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to another question I recently answered based on "common-interests" (or resources in the other post).

First, start with a single query of those interests you have and get those distinct users who are not you.  Then get those that YOU are the Follower, and the user is not someone you are already following.

Once you have those, its a simple join to posts by the user ID

To help optimize this query, on your tables you should have the following indexes

table           index
UserInterests   (userid)
UserInterests   (interestid, userid)
Followers       (userid, followerid)
Posts           (userid, postdate)

Additionally, if you want to limit the posts, such as current via a date, you might want that to be indexed as above to help easily apply a date criteria to your final JOIN to the posts table...  Joining posts on the user ID AND the postDate >= some date value...

I tried to break the section up with explicit extra line breaks between the logical relationships between the tables to follow how a->b->c is getting handled

```
SELECT 
      P.*
   from 
      ( select distinct 
              OtherUser.userid
           from 
              UserInterests Me

                 JOIN UserInterests OtherUser
                    ON UI1.InterestID = OtherUser.InterestID
                    AND NOT Me.UserID = OtherUser.UserID

                    LEFT JOIN Followers F
                       ON OtherUser.UserID = F.UserID
                       AND Me.UserID = F.FollowerID

           where Me.UserID = MyUserID
              AND F.UserID IS NULL ) as UsersNotFollowed

      JOIN Posts P
         ON UsersNotFollowed.UserID = P.UserID
```